# Bootstrap alert with login form

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap

I can't understand how can I show a bootstrap alert whenever a user successfully logs in, I've tried it but it is already showing the success or fail message and also it is showing undefined index of `$_SESSION['user_id']` which is id in my database.

```
    </div></header>
    <section class="clear" id="login-form"><center>
        <h1 style="font-size: 30px;">Login</h1><br>
        <?php 
            if ($_SESSION[''] == false) {
              echo '<center><div class="alert alert-success">Login Successful!!</div></center>';
            }
            else{
                echo '<center><div class="alert alert-warning">Login Error!!</div></center>';
            }
         ?>
      <form action="includes/login.inc.php" method="POST">
      <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username/E-mail" required><br>
      <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required><br>
      <button  name="submit">Login</button>


    </form></center></section>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

First you need to check the `user_in` from `$_SESSION` weather it is exist or not. If you set session after authentication, you can use the following:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['user_id']) && $_SESSION['user_id']) {
   echo '<center><div class="alert alert-success">Login Successful!!</div></center>';
} else {
   echo '<center><div class="alert alert-warning">Login Error!!</div></center>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use isset: whatever you set for the user during successful login in the session

```
  <?php 
        if (isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
          echo '<center><div class="alert alert-success">Login Successfull!!</div></center>';
        }
        else{
            echo '<center><div class="alert alert-warning">Login Error!!</div></center>';
        }
     ?>
```